# useeffect react cleanup not working with React Native modal

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

The effect for the modal looks like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('mounted')
    return () => {
        console.log('unounted')
   }
}, [])
```

When I try to call the modal conditionally like this :

```
modal ? <Suspense fallback={<ActivityIndicator/>}><Modal /></Suspense> : null
```

the console shows **mounted** when modal===true but doesn't show **unmounted** when modal===false.What's going on here?Does functional component cleanups don't work in React Native?Or is there something else happening behind the curtain?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Modal's [visible](https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal#visible) prop if you want to show the modal conditionally.

Add a state to the modal's father component like this:

```
const [isModalShown, setIsModalShown] = useState(false)
```

Then pass the state (`isModalShown`) to the prop and when you want to show the modal change the state to true (`setIsModalShown(true)`)